# How to create autocomplete form with MaterializeCss?

Tags: jquery-select2, materialize

I am looking for autocomplete form for MaterializeCss, any plugins for this? i has try to use select2 but that's css not looks good

Comment: Seems like we need to write the custom styles :/

Comment: What do you mean with autocomplete form?

Answer (score 11):

Materialize is an awesome library, I was able to get it to work.

```js
$('document').ready(function() {

  var input_selector = 'input[type=text], input[type=password], input[type=email], input[type=url], input[type=tel], input[type=number], input[type=search], textarea';
  
  
/**************************
* Auto complete plugin  *
*************************/
  
  
  $(input_selector).each(function() {
    var $input = $(this);

    if ($input.hasClass('autocomplete')) {
      var $array = $input.data('array'),
        $inputDiv = $input.closest('.input-field'); // Div to append on
      // Check if "data-array" isn't empty
      if ($array !== '') {
        // Create html element
        var $html = '<ul class="autocomplete-content hide">';

        for (var i = 0; i < $array.length; i++) {
          // If path and class aren't empty add image to auto complete else create normal element
          if ($array[i]['path'] !== '' && $array[i]['path'] !== undefined && $array[i]['path'] !== null && $array[i]['class'] !== undefined && $array[i]['class'] !== '') {
            $html += '<li class="autocomplete-option"><img src="' + $array[i]['path'] + '" class="' + $array[i]['class'] + '"><span>' + $array[i]['value'] + '</span></li>';
          } else {
            $html += '<li class="autocomplete-option"><span>' + $array[i]['value'] + '</span></li>';
          }
        }

        $html += '</ul>';
        $inputDiv.append($html); // Set ul in body
        // End create html element

        function highlight(string) {
          $('.autocomplete-content li').each(function() {
            var matchStart = $(this).text().toLowerCase().indexOf("" + string.toLowerCase() + ""),
              matchEnd = matchStart + string.length - 1,
              beforeMatch = $(this).text().slice(0, matchStart),
              matchText = $(this).text().slice(matchStart, matchEnd + 1),
              afterMatch = $(this).text().slice(matchEnd + 1);
            $(this).html("<span>" + beforeMatch + "<span class='highlight'>" + matchText + "</span>" + afterMatch + "</span>");
          });
        }

        // Perform search
        $(document).on('keyup', $input, function() {
          var $val = $input.val().trim(),
            $select = $('.autocomplete-content');
          // Check if the input isn't empty
          $select.css('width',$input.width());

          if ($val != '') {
            $select.children('li').addClass('hide');
            $select.children('li').filter(function() {
              $select.removeClass('hide'); // Show results

              // If text needs to highlighted
              if ($input.hasClass('highlight-matching')) {
                highlight($val);
              }
              var check = true;
              for (var i in $val) {
                if ($val[i].toLowerCase() !== $(this).text().toLowerCase()[i])
                  check = false;
              };
              return check ? $(this).text().toLowerCase().indexOf($val.toLowerCase()) !== -1 : false;
            }).removeClass('hide');
          } else {
            $select.children('li').addClass('hide');
          }
        });

        // Set input value
        $('.autocomplete-option').click(function() {
          $input.val($(this).text().trim());
          $('.autocomplete-option').addClass('hide');
        });
      } else {
        return false;
      }
    }
  });






});
```

```css
.autocomplete-content {

  position: absolute;

  background: #383838;

  margin-top: -.9rem;

}

.autocomplete-content li {

  clear: both;

  color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.87);

  cursor: pointer;

  line-height: 0;

  width: 100%;

  text-align: left;

  text-transform: none;

  padding: 10px;

}

.autocomplete-content li > span {

  color: #ffa726;

  font-size: .9rem;

  padding: 1.2rem;

  display: block;

}

.autocomplete-content li > span .highlight {

  color: #000000;

}

.autocomplete-content li img {

  height: 52px;

  width: 52px;

  padding: 5px;

  margin: 0 15px;

}

.autocomplete-content li:hover {

  background: #eee;

  cursor: pointer;

}

.autocomplete-content > li:hover {

  background: #292929;

}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.97.5/css/materialize.css" rel="stylesheet" />


<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<div class="row">
  <div class="input-field col s12">
    <label class="active">State</label>
    <input type="text" id="autocompleteState" class="autocomplete inputFields">

  </div>
</div>


<script>
  var stateData = [{
    value: "Alabama"
  }, {
    value: "Alaska"
  }, {
    value: "Arizona"
  }, {
    value: "Arkansas"
  }, {
    value: "California"
  }, {
    value: "Colorado"
  }, {
    value: "Connecticut"
  }, {
    value: "District of Columbia"
  }, {
    value: "Delaware"
  }, {
    value: "Florida"
  }, {
    value: "Georgia"
  }, {
    value: "Hawaii"
  }, {
    value: "Idaho"
  }, {
    value: "Illinois"
  }, {
    value: "Indiana"
  }, {
    value: "Iowa"
  }, {
    value: "Kansas"
  }, {
    value: "Kentucky"
  }, {
    value: "Louisiana"
  }, {
    value: "Maine"
  }, ];

  $('#autocompleteState').data('array', stateData);
</script>
```

Hope this helps people who are new to this just like me.:)

Answer (score 2):

**UPDATED 1/09/2016**:
Autocomplete is already available officially:
http://materializecss.com/forms.html#autocomplete

---

I was looking for exactly the same and I think We have been lucky. They added the autocomplete recently, (not yet in the documentation). But you can see the info here https://github.com/SuperDJ/materialize/commit/3648f74542e41c3b3be4596870b7485f6ebdf176#diff-e4535828acef79852aa104417c16fe3dR157

and the code:

- https://github.com/SuperDJ/materialize/blob/master/bin/materialize.css
- https://github.com/SuperDJ/materialize/blob/master/bin/materialize.js

Comment: Sadly it hasn't been merged into the official repository.

Comment: thanks @Saitama I have updated it, no you can find autocomplete on the current version of materializecss http://materializecss.com/forms.html#autocomplete

Answer (score 1):

```
(function (root, factory) {

    if(typeof module === 'object' && module.exports) {
        module.exports = factory(require('jquery'));
    } else if(typeof define === 'function' && define.amd) {
        define(['jquery'], factory);
    } else {
        factory(root.jQuery);
    }

}(this, function ($) {

    var template = function (text) {
        var matcher = new RegExp('<%=([\\s\\S]+?)%>|<%([\\s\\S]+?)%>|$', 'g');

        var escapes = {
            "'": "'",
            '\\': '\\',
            '\r': 'r',
            '\n': 'n',
            '\u2028': 'u2028',
            '\u2029': 'u2029'
        };

        var escapeRegExp = /\\|'|\r|\n|\u2028|\u2029/g;

        var escapeChar = function(match) {
            return '\\' + escapes[match];
        };

        var index = 0;
        var source = "__p+='";

        text.replace(matcher, function(match, interpolate, evaluate, offset) {
            source += text.slice(index, offset).replace(escapeRegExp, escapeChar);
            index = offset + match.length;
            if (match == "<% item.value %>")
                interpolate = " item.value ";
            if (interpolate) {
                source += "'+\n((__t=(" + interpolate + "))==null?'':__t)+\n'";
            } else if (evaluate) {
                source += "';\n" + evaluate + "\n__p+='";
            }

            return match;
        });

        source += "';\n";
        source = 'with(obj||{}){\n' + source + '}\n';
        source = "var __t,__p='',__j=Array.prototype.join," +
            "print=function(){__p+=__j.call(arguments,'');};\n" +
            source + 'return __p;\n';

        var render;

        try {
            render = new Function('obj', source);
        } catch (e) {
            e.source = source;
            throw e;
        }

        var _template = function(data) {
            return render.call(this, data);
        };

        _template.source = 'function(obj){\n' + source + '}';

        return _template;
    };

    var Autocomplete = function (el, options) {
        this.options = $.extend(true, {}, Autocomplete.defaults, options);
        this.$el = $(el);
        this.$wrapper = this.$el.parent();
        this.compiled = {};
        this.$dropdown = null;
        this.$appender = null;
        this.$hidden = null;
        this.resultCache = {};
        this.value = '';
        this.initialize();
    };

    Autocomplete.defaults = {
        cacheable: true,
        limit: 10,
        multiple: {
            enable: false,
            maxSize: 4,
            onExist: function (item) {
                Materialize.toast('Tag: ' + item.text + '(' + item.id + ') is already added!', 2000);
            },
            onExceed: function (maxSize, item) {
                Materialize.toast('Can\'t add over ' + maxSize + ' tags!', 2000);
            },
            onAppend: function (item) {
                var self = this;
                self.$el.removeClass('active');
                self.$el.click();
            },
            onRemove: function (item) {
                var self = this;
                self.$el.removeClass('active');
                self.$el.click();
            }
        },
        hidden: {
            enable: true,
            el: '',
            inputName: '',
            required: false
        },
        appender: {
            el: '',
            tagName: 'ul',
            className: 'ac-appender',
            tagTemplate: '<div class="chip" data-id="<%= item.id %>" data-value="<% item.value %> data-text="<% item.text %>" "><%= item.text %>(<%= item.id %>)<i class="material-icons close">close</i></div>'
        },
        dropdown: {
            el: '',
            tagName: 'ul',
            className: 'ac-dropdown',
            itemTemplate: '<li class="ac-item" data-id="<%= item.id %>" data-value="<% item.value %>" data-text="<%= item.text %>" ><a href="javascript:void(0)"><%= item.text %></a></li>',
            noItem: ''
        },
        handlers: {
            'setValue': '.ac-dropdown .ac-item',
            '.ac-appender .ac-tag .close': 'remove'
        },
        getData: function (value, callback) {
            callback(value, []);
        },
        onSelect: function (item) { },
        onRemove: function (item) { alert('delete'); },
        ignoreCase: true,
        throttling: true,
        showListOnFocus: false,
        minLength:0
    };

    Autocomplete.prototype = {
        constructor: Autocomplete,
        initialize: function () {
            var self = this;
            var timer;
            var fetching = false;

            function getItemsHtml (list) {
                var itemsHtml = '';

                if (!list.length) {
                    return self.options.dropdown.noItem;
                }

                list.forEach(function (item, idx) {

                    if (idx >= self.options.limit) {
                        return false;
                    }

                    itemsHtml += self.compiled.item({ 'item': item});
                });

                return itemsHtml;
            }

            function handleList (value, list) {
                var itemsHtml = getItemsHtml(list);
                var currentValue = self.$el.val();

                if (self.options.ignoreCase) {
                    currentValue = currentValue.toUpperCase();
                }

                if (self.options.cacheable && !self.resultCache.hasOwnProperty(value)) {
                    self.resultCache[value] = list;
                }

                if (value !== currentValue) {
                    return false;
                }

                if(itemsHtml) {
                    self.$dropdown.html(itemsHtml);
                    self.$dropdown.show();
                } else {
                    self.$dropdown.hide();
                }

            }

            self.value = self.options.multiple.enable ? [] : '';

            self.compiled.tag = template(self.options.appender.tagTemplate);
            self.compiled.item = template(self.options.dropdown.itemTemplate);

            self.render();
            if (self.options.showListOnFocus) {
                self.$el.on('focus', function (e) {
                    if (self.options.throttling) {
                        clearTimeout(timer);
                        timer = setTimeout(function () {

                            self.options.getData('', handleList);
                        }, 200);
                        return true;
                    }

                    // self.$dropdown.show();
                });
            }

            self.$el.on('input', function (e) {
                var $t = $(this);
                var value = $t.val();

                if (!value) {
                    self.$dropdown.hide();
                    return false;
                }

                if (self.options.ignoreCase) {
                    value = value.toUpperCase();
                }

                if (self.resultCache.hasOwnProperty(value) && self.resultCache[value]) {
                    handleList(value, self.resultCache[value]);
                    return true;
                }

                if (self.options.showListOnFocus || self.options.minLength <= value.length) {
                    if (self.options.throttling) {
                        clearTimeout(timer);
                        timer = setTimeout(function () {
                            self.options.getData(value, handleList);
                        }, 200);
                        return true;
                    }

                    self.options.getData(value, handleList);
                }
            });

            self.$el.on('keydown', function (e) {
                var $t = $(this);
                var keyCode = e.keyCode;
                var $items, $hover;
                // BACKSPACE KEY
                if (keyCode == '8' && !$t.val()) {

                    if (!self.options.multiple.enable) {
                        return true;
                    }

                    if (!self.value.length) {
                        return true;
                    }

                    var lastItem = self.value[self.value.length - 1];
                    self.remove(lastItem);
                    return false;
                }
                // UP DOWN ARROW KEY
                if (keyCode == '38' || keyCode == '40') {

                    $items = self.$dropdown.find('[data-id]');

                    if (!$items.size()) {
                        return false;
                    }

                    $hover = $items.filter('.ac-hover');

                    if (!$hover.size()) {
                        $items.removeClass('ac-hover');
                        $items.eq(keyCode == '40' ? 0 : -1).addClass('ac-hover');
                    } else {
                        var index = $hover.index();
                        $items.removeClass('ac-hover');
                        $items.eq(keyCode == '40' ? (index + 1) % $items.size() : index - 1).addClass('ac-hover');
                    }

                    return false;
                }
                // ENTER KEY CODE
                if (keyCode == '13') {
                    $items = self.$dropdown.find('[data-id]');

                    if (!$items.size()) {
                        return false;
                    }

                    $hover = $items.filter('.ac-hover');

                    if (!$hover.size()) {
                        return false;
                    }

                    self.setValue({
                        id: $hover.data('id'),
                        text: $hover.data('text'),
                        value: $hover.data('value')
                    });

                    return false;
                }

            });

            self.$dropdown.on('click', '[data-id]', function (e) {
                var $t = $(this);
                var item = {
                    id: $t.data('id'),
                    text: $t.data('text'),
                    value : $t.data('value')
                };

                self.setValue(item);
            });

            self.$appender.on('click', '[data-id] .close', function (e) {
                var $t = $(this);
                var $li = $t.closest('[data-id');
                var item = {
                    id: $li.data('id'),
                    text: $li.data('text'),
                    value:$t.data('value')
                };

                self.remove(item);
            });

        },
        render: function () {
            var self = this;

            if (self.options.dropdown.el) {
                self.$dropdown = $(self.options.dropdown.el);
            } else {
                self.$dropdown = $(document.createElement(self.options.dropdown.tagName));
                self.$dropdown.insertAfter(self.$el);
            }

            self.$dropdown.addClass(self.options.dropdown.className);

            if (self.options.appender.el) {
                self.$appender = $(self.options.appender.el);
            } else {
                self.$appender = $(document.createElement(self.options.appender.tagName));
                self.$appender.insertBefore(self.$el);
            }

            if (self.options.hidden.enable) {

                if (self.options.hidden.el) {
                    self.$hidden = $(self.options.hidden.el);
                } else {
                    self.$hidden = $('<input type="hidden" class="validate" />');
                    self.$wrapper.append(self.$hidden);
                }

                if (self.options.hidden.inputName) {
                    self.$el.attr('name', self.options.hidden.inputName);
                }

                if (self.options.hidden.required) {
                    self.$hidden.attr('required', 'required');
                }

            }

            self.$appender.addClass(self.options.appender.className);

        },
        setValue: function (item) {
            var self = this;

            if (self.options.multiple.enable) {
                self.append(item);
            } else {
                self.select(item);
            }

        },
        append: function (item) {
            var self = this;
            var $tag = self.compiled.tag({ 'item': item });

            if (self.value.some(function (selectedItem) {
                    return selectedItem.id === item.id;
                })) {

                if ('function' === typeof self.options.multiple.onExist) {
                    self.options.multiple.onExist.call(this, item);
                }

                return false;
            }

            if (self.value.length >= self.options.multiple.maxSize) {

                if ('function' === typeof self.options.multiple.onExceed) {
                    self.options.multiple.onExceed.call(this, self.options.multiple.maxSize);
                }

                return false;
            }

            self.value.push(item);
            self.$appender.append($tag);

            var valueStr = self.value.map(function (selectedItem) {
                return selectedItem.id;
            }).join(',');

            if (self.options.hidden.enable) {
                self.$hidden.val(valueStr);
            }

            self.$el.val('');
            self.$el.data('value', valueStr);
            self.$dropdown.html('').hide();

            if ('function' === typeof self.options.multiple.onAppend) {
                self.options.multiple.onAppend.call(self, item);
            }

        },
        remove: function (item) {
            var self = this;

            self.$appender.find('[data-id="' + item.id + '"]').remove();
            self.value = self.value.filter(function (selectedItem) {
                return selectedItem.id !== item.id;
            });

            var valueStr = self.value.map(function (selectedItem) {
                return selectedItem.id;
            }).join(',');

            if (self.options.hidden.enable) {
                self.$hidden.val(valueStr);
                self.$el.data('value', valueStr);
            }

            self.$dropdown.html('').hide();

            if ('function' === typeof self.options.multiple.onRemove) {
                self.options.multiple.onRemove.call(self, item);
            }
            self.options.onRemove(item);
        },
        select: function (item) {
            var self = this;

            self.value = item.text;
            self.$el.val(item.text);
            self.$el.data('value', item.id);
            self.$dropdown.html('').hide();
            if (self.options.hidden.enable) {
                self.$hidden.val(item.id);
            }
            self.options.onSelect(item);
        }
    };

    $.fn.materialize_autocomplete = function (options) {
        var el = this;
        var $el = $(el).eq(0);
        var instance = $el.data('autocomplete');

        if (instance && arguments.length) {
            return instance;
        }

        var autocomplete = new Autocomplete(el, options);
        $el.data('autocomplete', autocomplete);
        $el.dropdown();
        return autocomplete;
    };

}));
```

down load this js and save inside your js folder jquery.materialize-autocomplete.js and u can over ride onSelect,minLength,showListOnFocus

Answer (score 1):

Visit the link for demo https://ampersandacademy.com/demo/autocomplete/

you can easily achieve the autocomplete functionality using the Devberidge plugin.

Get Devbridge plugin using https://github.com/devbridge/jQuery-Autocomplete

```
 <script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function() {


          $("#country").devbridgeAutocomplete({
            //lookup: countries,
            serviceUrl:"getCountry.php", //tell the script where to send requests
              type:'POST',


              //callback just to show it's working
              onSelect: function (suggestion) {
                 // $('#selection').html('You selected: ' + suggestion.value + ', ' + suggestion.data);
                },
            showNoSuggestionNotice: true,
            noSuggestionNotice: 'Sorry, no matching results',


          });

});
```

Here the getCountry.php file returns the JSON data. For more info visit https://ampersandacademy.com/tutorials/materialize-css/materialize-css-framework-ajax-autocomplete-example-using-php

Answer (score 0):

According to the commit done by SuperDJ (https://goo.gl/0Mbrtg), I didn't manage to get it works...

Here is the code :

```
  <div class="row">
                <div class="col s12">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="input-field col s12">
                            <input type="text" id="autocomplete" class="autocomplete highlight-matching" data-array='[{"value": "example","path": "","class": ""},{"value": "example 2","path": "","class": ""},{"value": "test","path": "","class": ""}]'>
                            <label for="autocomplete">Autocomplete</label>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
```

Here is a codepen test :

http://codepen.io/anthonyvialleton/pen/BjPjKM

Need some help to get this work.

Comment: I think is not yet in the cdn sources ;), maybe soon, you need to add the sources https://github.com/SuperDJ/materialize/blob/master/bin/materialize.css

https://github.com/SuperDJ/materialize/blob/master/bin/materialize.js

Comment: Yes, this has not been merged yet... so it's not usable for production purposes. We'll have to wait all the improvements and the merge.

Comment: It's a fork, it's not the official project : https://github.com/Dogfalo/materialize

Answer (score 0):

As per, [here](http://materializecss.com/forms.html#autocomplete).

You just need to do this simple thing (From the example there only):

`HTML:`

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col s12">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="input-field col s12">
          <i class="material-icons prefix">textsms</i>
          <input type="text" id="autocomplete-input" class="autocomplete">
          <label for="autocomplete-input">Autocomplete</label>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

`JS:`

```
$('input.autocomplete').autocomplete({
    data: {
      "Apple": null,
      "Microsoft": null,
      "Google": null
   }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
(function (root, factory) {

    if(typeof module === 'object' && module.exports) {
        module.exports = factory(require('jquery'));
    } else if(typeof define === 'function' && define.amd) {
        define(['jquery'], factory);
    } else {
        factory(root.jQuery);
    }

}(this, function ($) {

    var template = function (text) {
        var matcher = new RegExp('<%=([\\s\\S]+?)%>|<%([\\s\\S]+?)%>|$', 'g');

        var escapes = {
            "'": "'",
            '\\': '\\',
            '\r': 'r',
            '\n': 'n',
            '\u2028': 'u2028',
            '\u2029': 'u2029'
        };

        var escapeRegExp = /\\|'|\r|\n|\u2028|\u2029/g;

        var escapeChar = function(match) {
            return '\\' + escapes[match];
        };

        var index = 0;
        var source = "__p+='";

        text.replace(matcher, function(match, interpolate, evaluate, offset) {
            source += text.slice(index, offset).replace(escapeRegExp, escapeChar);
            index = offset + match.length;
            if (match == "<% item.value %>")
                interpolate = " item.value ";
            if (interpolate) {
                source += "'+\n((__t=(" + interpolate + "))==null?'':__t)+\n'";
            } else if (evaluate) {
                source += "';\n" + evaluate + "\n__p+='";
            }

            return match;
        });

        source += "';\n";
        source = 'with(obj||{}){\n' + source + '}\n';
        source = "var __t,__p='',__j=Array.prototype.join," +
            "print=function(){__p+=__j.call(arguments,'');};\n" +
            source + 'return __p;\n';

        var render;

        try {
            render = new Function('obj', source);
        } catch (e) {
            e.source = source;
            throw e;
        }

        var _template = function(data) {
            return render.call(this, data);
        };

        _template.source = 'function(obj){\n' + source + '}';

        return _template;
    };

    var Autocomplete = function (el, options) {
        this.options = $.extend(true, {}, Autocomplete.defaults, options);
        this.$el = $(el);
        this.$wrapper = this.$el.parent();
        this.compiled = {};
        this.$dropdown = null;
        this.$appender = null;
        this.$hidden = null;
        this.resultCache = {};
        this.value = '';
        this.initialize();
    };

    Autocomplete.defaults = {
        cacheable: true,
        limit: 10,
        multiple: {
            enable: false,
            maxSize: 4,
            onExist: function (item) {
                Materialize.toast('Tag: ' + item.text + '(' + item.id + ') is already added!', 2000);
            },
            onExceed: function (maxSize, item) {
                Materialize.toast('Can\'t add over ' + maxSize + ' tags!', 2000);
            },
            onAppend: function (item) {
                var self = this;
                self.$el.removeClass('active');
                self.$el.click();
            },
            onRemove: function (item) {
                var self = this;
                self.$el.removeClass('active');
                self.$el.click();
            }
        },
        hidden: {
            enable: true,
            el: '',
            inputName: '',
            required: false
        },
        appender: {
            el: '',
            tagName: 'ul',
            className: 'ac-appender',
            tagTemplate: '<div class="chip" data-id="<%= item.id %>" data-value="<% item.value %> data-text="<% item.text %>" "><%= item.text %>(<%= item.id %>)<i class="material-icons close">close</i></div>'
        },
        dropdown: {
            el: '',
            tagName: 'ul',
            className: 'ac-dropdown',
            itemTemplate: '<li class="ac-item" data-id="<%= item.id %>" data-value="<% item.value %>" data-text="<%= item.text %>" ><a href="javascript:void(0)"><%= item.text %></a></li>',
            noItem: ''
        },
        handlers: {
            'setValue': '.ac-dropdown .ac-item',
            '.ac-appender .ac-tag .close': 'remove'
        },
        getData: function (value, callback) {
            callback(value, []);
        },
        onSelect: function (item) { },
        onRemove: function (item) { alert('delete'); },
        ignoreCase: true,
        throttling: true,
        showListOnFocus: false,
        minLength:0
    };

    Autocomplete.prototype = {
        constructor: Autocomplete,
        initialize: function () {
            var self = this;
            var timer;
            var fetching = false;

            function getItemsHtml (list) {
                var itemsHtml = '';

                if (!list.length) {
                    return self.options.dropdown.noItem;
                }

                list.forEach(function (item, idx) {

                    if (idx >= self.options.limit) {
                        return false;
                    }

                    itemsHtml += self.compiled.item({ 'item': item});
                });

                return itemsHtml;
            }

            function handleList (value, list) {
                var itemsHtml = getItemsHtml(list);
                var currentValue = self.$el.val();

                if (self.options.ignoreCase) {
                    currentValue = currentValue.toUpperCase();
                }

                if (self.options.cacheable && !self.resultCache.hasOwnProperty(value)) {
                    self.resultCache[value] = list;
                }

                if (value !== currentValue) {
                    return false;
                }

                if(itemsHtml) {
                    self.$dropdown.html(itemsHtml);
                    self.$dropdown.show();
                } else {
                    self.$dropdown.hide();
                }

            }

            self.value = self.options.multiple.enable ? [] : '';

            self.compiled.tag = template(self.options.appender.tagTemplate);
            self.compiled.item = template(self.options.dropdown.itemTemplate);

            self.render();
            if (self.options.showListOnFocus) {
                self.$el.on('focus', function (e) {
                    if (self.options.throttling) {
                        clearTimeout(timer);
                        timer = setTimeout(function () {

                            self.options.getData('', handleList);
                        }, 200);
                        return true;
                    }

                    // self.$dropdown.show();
                });
            }

            self.$el.on('input', function (e) {
                var $t = $(this);
                var value = $t.val();

                if (!value) {
                    self.$dropdown.hide();
                    return false;
                }

                if (self.options.ignoreCase) {
                    value = value.toUpperCase();
                }

                if (self.resultCache.hasOwnProperty(value) && self.resultCache[value]) {
                    handleList(value, self.resultCache[value]);
                    return true;
                }

                if (self.options.showListOnFocus || self.options.minLength <= value.length) {
                    if (self.options.throttling) {
                        clearTimeout(timer);
                        timer = setTimeout(function () {
                            self.options.getData(value, handleList);
                        }, 200);
                        return true;
                    }

                    self.options.getData(value, handleList);
                }
            });

            self.$el.on('keydown', function (e) {
                var $t = $(this);
                var keyCode = e.keyCode;
                var $items, $hover;
                // BACKSPACE KEY
                if (keyCode == '8' && !$t.val()) {

                    if (!self.options.multiple.enable) {
                        return true;
                    }

                    if (!self.value.length) {
                        return true;
                    }

                    var lastItem = self.value[self.value.length - 1];
                    self.remove(lastItem);
                    return false;
                }
                // UP DOWN ARROW KEY
                if (keyCode == '38' || keyCode == '40') {

                    $items = self.$dropdown.find('[data-id]');

                    if (!$items.size()) {
                        return false;
                    }

                    $hover = $items.filter('.ac-hover');

                    if (!$hover.size()) {
                        $items.removeClass('ac-hover');
                        $items.eq(keyCode == '40' ? 0 : -1).addClass('ac-hover');
                    } else {
                        var index = $hover.index();
                        $items.removeClass('ac-hover');
                        $items.eq(keyCode == '40' ? (index + 1) % $items.size() : index - 1).addClass('ac-hover');
                    }

                    return false;
                }
                // ENTER KEY CODE
                if (keyCode == '13') {
                    $items = self.$dropdown.find('[data-id]');

                    if (!$items.size()) {
                        return false;
                    }

                    $hover = $items.filter('.ac-hover');

                    if (!$hover.size()) {
                        return false;
                    }

                    self.setValue({
                        id: $hover.data('id'),
                        text: $hover.data('text'),
                        value: $hover.data('value')
                    });

                    return false;
                }

            });

            self.$dropdown.on('click', '[data-id]', function (e) {
                var $t = $(this);
                var item = {
                    id: $t.data('id'),
                    text: $t.data('text'),
                    value : $t.data('value')
                };

                self.setValue(item);
            });

            self.$appender.on('click', '[data-id] .close', function (e) {
                var $t = $(this);
                var $li = $t.closest('[data-id');
                var item = {
                    id: $li.data('id'),
                    text: $li.data('text'),
                    value:$t.data('value')
                };

                self.remove(item);
            });

        },
        render: function () {
            var self = this;

            if (self.options.dropdown.el) {
                self.$dropdown = $(self.options.dropdown.el);
            } else {
                self.$dropdown = $(document.createElement(self.options.dropdown.tagName));
                self.$dropdown.insertAfter(self.$el);
            }

            self.$dropdown.addClass(self.options.dropdown.className);

            if (self.options.appender.el) {
                self.$appender = $(self.options.appender.el);
            } else {
                self.$appender = $(document.createElement(self.options.appender.tagName));
                self.$appender.insertBefore(self.$el);
            }

            if (self.options.hidden.enable) {

                if (self.options.hidden.el) {
                    self.$hidden = $(self.options.hidden.el);
                } else {
                    self.$hidden = $('<input type="hidden" class="validate" />');
                    self.$wrapper.append(self.$hidden);
                }

                if (self.options.hidden.inputName) {
                    self.$el.attr('name', self.options.hidden.inputName);
                }

                if (self.options.hidden.required) {
                    self.$hidden.attr('required', 'required');
                }

            }

            self.$appender.addClass(self.options.appender.className);

        },
        setValue: function (item) {
            var self = this;

            if (self.options.multiple.enable) {
                self.append(item);
            } else {
                self.select(item);
            }

        },
        append: function (item) {
            var self = this;
            var $tag = self.compiled.tag({ 'item': item });

            if (self.value.some(function (selectedItem) {
                    return selectedItem.id === item.id;
                })) {

                if ('function' === typeof self.options.multiple.onExist) {
                    self.options.multiple.onExist.call(this, item);
                }

                return false;
            }

            if (self.value.length >= self.options.multiple.maxSize) {

                if ('function' === typeof self.options.multiple.onExceed) {
                    self.options.multiple.onExceed.call(this, self.options.multiple.maxSize);
                }

                return false;
            }

            self.value.push(item);
            self.$appender.append($tag);

            var valueStr = self.value.map(function (selectedItem) {
                return selectedItem.id;
            }).join(',');

            if (self.options.hidden.enable) {
                self.$hidden.val(valueStr);
            }

            self.$el.val('');
            self.$el.data('value', valueStr);
            self.$dropdown.html('').hide();

            if ('function' === typeof self.options.multiple.onAppend) {
                self.options.multiple.onAppend.call(self, item);
            }

        },
        remove: function (item) {
            var self = this;

            self.$appender.find('[data-id="' + item.id + '"]').remove();
            self.value = self.value.filter(function (selectedItem) {
                return selectedItem.id !== item.id;
            });

            var valueStr = self.value.map(function (selectedItem) {
                return selectedItem.id;
            }).join(',');

            if (self.options.hidden.enable) {
                self.$hidden.val(valueStr);
                self.$el.data('value', valueStr);
            }

            self.$dropdown.html('').hide();

            if ('function' === typeof self.options.multiple.onRemove) {
                self.options.multiple.onRemove.call(self, item);
            }
            self.options.onRemove(item);
        },
        select: function (item) {
            var self = this;

            self.value = item.text;
            self.$el.val(item.text);
            self.$el.data('value', item.id);
            self.$dropdown.html('').hide();
            if (self.options.hidden.enable) {
                self.$hidden.val(item.id);
            }
            self.options.onSelect(item);
        }
    };

    $.fn.materialize_autocomplete = function (options) {
        var el = this;
        var $el = $(el).eq(0);
        var instance = $el.data('autocomplete');

        if (instance && arguments.length) {
            return instance;
        }

        var autocomplete = new Autocomplete(el, options);
        $el.data('autocomplete', autocomplete);
        $el.dropdown();
        return autocomplete;
    };

}));
```

You can use the above .js file and you can over ride

```
Onselect
 showListOnFocus: false,
            minLength:2
```

according to your requirement and it will work.

Answer (score 0):

Just write the Initialisation script inside **$(document).ready(function(){});**

i.e.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('input.autocomplete').autocomplete({
        data: {
            "Apple": null,
            "Microsoft": null,
            "Google": null
        }
     });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned above, autocomplete has been added the the materialize framework but it is still pretty limited. I'm waiting for a solution that supports values (ex Ids) icons and text.

Re: https://github.com/Dogfalo/materialize/issues/4086

Comment: Same here. Something with ID's would be a much better solution as it has more uses.