# materialize Suggestion Dropdown on Search Form on key press(MaterializeCSS)

Tags: javascript, css, materialize

```
<nav>
<div class="nav-wrapper">
  <form>
    <div class="input-field">
      <input id="search" type="search" required>
      <label for="search"><i class="material-icons">search</i></label>
      <i class="material-icons">close</i>
    </div>
  </form>
</div></nav>
```

does anyone know how to add dropping down suggestions when someone write letters on search box?

using Materialize CSS

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to create autocomplete form with MaterializeCss?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34222775/how-to-create-autocomplete-form-with-materializecss)

Answer (score 1):

Use the autocomplete class on the input. Then initialize it with an object that contains the options.

$('input.autocomplete').autocomplete({
    data: {
      "Apple": null,
      "Microsoft": null,
      "Google": 'http://placehold.it/250x250'
    }
  });

Refer to http://materializecss.com/forms.html

Comment: This does not work with the search bar component for some reason.